# What's the best practice to hide a form-processing file, from direct access?

Tags: php, forms, post, http-post, form-submit

I have a form with this code:

```
<form action="/directory/" method="POST" target="_blank">
<input name="hello" type="hidden" value="something"/>
<input name="there" type="hidden" value="something"/>
```

Inside the `/directory/` folder, I've placed an `index.php` file that would process the form, with this sort of code:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['hello']));

switch ($_POST['hello']) {

    case "1":
        $var1 = "word1";
        break;

    case "2":
        $var1 = "word2";
        break;

    default:
        $var1 = "other";
}
?>

<?php 

if(isset($_POST['there']));

switch ($_POST['there']) {

    case "1":
        $var2 = "word3";
        break;

    case "2":
        $var2 = "word4";
        break;

    default:
        $var2 = "other";
}
?>   
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div>
Content, <?php echo $var1; ?>, Content, <?php echo $var2; ?>, Content.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But I don't want a curious user to be able to go directly to `mydomain.com/directory/` and see the output of `index.php`, unless he got there through the form.

So how do I either hide/make `index.php` inaccessible, or maybe change something in the .php, while keeping more or less the `action="/directory/"` tag, the same?

What are the best possible practices?

Comment: If you completely want the `/directory/` to not  be accessed directly, you can create `.htaccess` file inside the directory and save in it `deny from all`. Worked for me.

Comment: just tried it, and this denies access when using the form as well.

Comment: Try `deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1`

Comment: nope, that didn't work either..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I don't want a curious user to be able to go directly to mydomain.com/directory/ and see the output of index.php, unless he got there through the form.

I don't think you understand how HTTP requests work.  When the user submits the form, they didn't necessarily get there *through the form*.  They're just submitting a POST request to a particular resource (in this case, `/directory/index.php`).  In order for that resource to accept POST requests from users, they need to be able to access it.

All the form does is provide the user with information about what that resource expects in a POST request, such as the values it's looking for.  But such a request can also be made manually, the server doesn't know the difference.  You can restrict access to that resource to be *only* POST requests if you'd like.  One way to accomplish that might be to have the page check for the existence of `$_POST[]` and make sure it has the values it expects (which you kind of do already).

If you want to ensure that users must first request the form and only *then* perform the POST request then you'll probably need to track that statefulness in some way.  One approach is to provide a unique token as part of the form.  A GUID in a hidden form field works well for this.  When you display the form, you would track in your database the token that was generated (maybe even assign a time stamp to it so it can expire).  Then in your POST handler page you'd compare the submitted token against known tokens from the database, displaying an error if it doesn't match.  This would allow you to reject POST requests which don't contain a known token, requiring the user to first request the form before performing the POST.

---

In response to comments below, you can return an error instead of displaying content if some precondition of the page fails.  This *could* be something as simple as:

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
?>
    <p>This is an error message.</p>
<?php
    } else {

?>
    <p>This is the normal page content.</p>
<?php
    }
?>
```

There are lots of different ways to organize that.  Maybe end the response instead of putting the rest in an `else` block?  My PHP is a bit rusty, but you should be able to figure something out.  You can even just return an HTTP error code and let the user figure it out:

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    } else {
?>
    <p>This is the normal page content.</p>
<?php
    }
?>
```

There are lots of [HTTP error codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) to choose from for this.  Ultimately the logic and layout is whatever you'd like it to be.  You control what content is displayed to the user and the logical conditions under which that content is displayed.

Comment: I'm afraid this token/GUID really exceeds my knowledge, and also sounds pretty complicated for what I'm trying to achieve. In the second paragraph, do you mean I should just display the user different content, by checking if `$var` values are set to `other`? How do I do that?

Comment: @rockyraw: It's not really that complicated, and it really is a standard way of tracking the statefulness of which users have made which requests (preventing users from mass-posting a form many times, for example).  All it involves is generating an identifier and storing it in the database.  As for displaying different content, sure you can absolutely do that.  When the POST handler first loads you can check if the request contains what you expect it to and, if it doesn't, display an error instead of the page's content.  You're in full control of what you display on any given page.

Comment: I'm currently not using any database on the website though.
Can you give me an example php snippet of how to display such an error? would that be some sort of an if/else command, with the if making a url redirect to an error page? not sure how it should be best done. thanks!

Comment: Great, I think this is exactly what I need. is there any drawback or possible hack for this? for example, compared to the first method you had described?

Comment: @rockyraw: Well, a savvy user could still reverse-engineer the form and repeat it.  So they could perhaps get the form once, load the key/value pairs into a program, and POST it to the page many times over and over.  That may or may not be an issue for you.  If it's not, no problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into htaccess restrictions, visit this link :

http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess.shtml

Comment: I took a look and not so sure which of the rules listed there would be appropriate for my very specific purpose...